# How to increase Stack size for a Webservice in .Net 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, web-services, stack-overflow, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have an issue with the stack limit in my webservice.
I was suggested to read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tom/stack-sizes-in-iis-affects-asp-net) by fellow members of this forum, but I do not have an idea how to run the EDITBIN.

I am using VS2008 on Windows 7 (IIS7)
Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to edit the binaries. See "Michael Reyeros" response on the link you posted.

Comment: hi Martin, I read that thing, but I think the easiest thing to do at the moment is to add the stack size to 1MB and this will solve the problem. I am sure that it will not increase more than that even in the future because the recursive function cannot go unlimited.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running out of stack, it's usually a good idea to analyse exactly *why* you're running out and change your design appropriately. Increasing the stack size (whether programmatically or by editing the binary) will usually just mean you can handle a larger data set to recurse through, or something similar.

I would strongly recommend that you work out exactly what's going on in your stack before increasing the size. You may end up making a recursive approach iterative - or you may just find you have a bug at the moment.

Comment: thanks Jon, i have already done that but since the iteration is done to process several images of size 64*64, I cannot do better (at least for the time being)

Comment: @mouthpiec: Processing images should take *heap* space rather than *stack* space. Have you really worked out why there's so much stack being used?